# Laravel debug/stacktrace page tries to open phpstorm instead of VSCode when clicking on line

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

Clicking on the 'pencil' icon on the stack trace page tries to open phpstorm instead of vscode. and i don't even have phpstorm installed. I would like the button to open vscode instead.

[image: I don't even have PHPStorm installed]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to configure which IDE is used.

In your .env file you can set variable to choose IDE for debug page as below:

```
IGNITION_EDITOR=vscode
```

Please, check the documentation: https://flareapp.io/docs/ignition-for-laravel/configuration#setting-your-editor

Comment: had to set 'IGNITION_EDITOR' in .env to 'vscode'. thanks a lot!

Comment: Supported Editors: "phpstorm", "vscode", "vscode-insiders", "sublime", "atom".
You can find it in config/ignition.php